# Need help with SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I need query on **Case** and its child object **'Case Status History'** such that I need cases whose **Status='closed'** and I need the latest **'Case Status History'** record for each case. The **'Name'** field of **'Case Status History'** record is of **Autonumber** type so I am trying to get the **largest name** records of **'Case Status History'** for each case. I was trying the bellow query but its not working.

```
Select Id , Subject , Status , 
       ( Select Id,Name,parent_case__r.subject 
         FROM Case_Status_History__c 
         where isdeleted = false group by name DESC limit 1 ) 
  FROM Case where Status ='Closed'
```

Is it possible to get records by SOQL in the way I want ?

Thanks!

Comment: the above query will work if you remove the `group by name` from inner query.. I guess

Comment: @sfdcweb            Select Id , Subject , Status , ( Select Id,Name,parent_case__r.subject FROM Case_Status_History__c where isdeleted = false DESC limit 1 ) FROM Case where Status ='Closed'  . Even this is not working.

Comment: I am receiving the error 'Unknown error parsing query'

Comment: Ruchi .. one more issue you need to specify relationship name of Case_status_history object.. I think that will be `Case_Status_History__r ` so your inner query will be like `Select Id , Subject , Status , ( Select Id,Name,parent_case__r.subject FROM Case_Status_History__r where isdeleted = false DESC limit 1 ) FROM Case where Status ='Closed'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, Status, 
   ( SELECT Id, Name, parent_case__r.Subject 
     FROM Case_Status_History__c 
     WHERE isdeleted = false LIMIT 1 ) 
FROM Case 
WHERE Status ='Closed'
```

(You removed `GROUP BY` but didn't remove the `DESC` part)

However, you might want to change the original `GROUP BY Name DESC` to `ORDER BY Name DESC` ie:

```
SELECT Id, Subject, Status, 
   ( SELECT Id, Name, parent_case__r.Subject 
   FROM Case_Status_History__c 
   WHERE isdeleted = false ORDER BY Name LIMIT 1 ) 
FROM Case 
WHERE Status ='Closed'
```

Comment: Harner    : Is it possible to get the same thing in apex ? Means I want all the largest 'Case_Status_History__c records' for each CASE. Is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can query this to a list of Cases. You can then access the Case_Status_History__c record - it's normally a list within the list, but I'm not totally sure what it is if you limit it to 1... prob still a list.